# working with xamarin code templates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I am trying understand hot xamarin code templates work and how to use it.

By reading [the manual](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introducing_xamarin_studio/) it appears the a user can select the code templates by clicking on it or hitting enter on it. Just like in eclipse and intellij.

But this seems not to work the same way in xamarin.

For example after I typed "try" in the editor and hit `ctrl+space` to get the code complete. Now I am presented with options to select. When I select `try` and click or hit Enter on it nothing happens. The code complete window just closes and the template is not added.

The animated gif demonstrates it with the mouse click event. But the behavior is the same for key events. Also no matter what I template I select it is never pasted.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but not even tapping tab twice works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press tab key after you have selected the text. You basically have to press tab - tab. The first tab will complete the `try` text in your example. You may have only typed in `t` or `tr`. The second tab key press will expand the code template.

The behaviour is similar to Visual Studio. The difference is that Visual Studio gives you more information in the completion window that appears telling you that you need to press the tab key twice. Screenshot from Visual Studio is shown below.

[image: Visual Studio code template insertion completion window]

With the screenshot above pressing tab once will close the completion window but not insert the code for the try template. Pressing tab again will insert the code template text.

Comment: This is so different what I am used to. Without your help I would assume it is forever broken.